# django-unicorn resets mounted data after button click

Tags: django

I've built several small apps over the last weeks and stumbled every time over the same problem I couldn't figure out a solution with the docs or a google search.

## TL;DR

I can't keep the results of a queryset initialized inside `__init__` or `mount()` after clicking a button and changing any other value unrelated to the queryset. Is there a way to save/cache the results?

## Simple Example

### Initial position

###### components/simple_unicorn.py

```
from django_unicorn.components import UnicornView
from any.app.models import MyObject

class SimpleUnicornView(UnicornView):
    # Initialize my sample objects empty as I don't have any filter data, yet
    objects: MyObject = MyObject.objects.none()
    # A single filter value - In reality those are multiple buttons
    filter_y: str = ""
    # any variable unrelated to the queryset
    show_button_x: bool = False

    def mount(self):
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        self.objects = MyObject.objects.filter(any_value=self.filter_y)
        # the execution of this query takes very long

    def updated_filter_y(self, value):
        # after changing variables related to the qs it is obvious the reload the data
        self.load_data()

    # this is where the problem pops up
    def toggle_button_x(self):
        # I'm only changing a variable not connected to the loaded data
        self.show_button_x = not self.show_button_x
        # Now I must execute the query again, otherwise self.objects is empty
        self.load_data()
```

###### simple.html

```
<div>

  <select unicorn:model="filter_y">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="A">Filter for "A"</option>
    <option value="B">Filter for "B"</option>
  </select>

  <ul>
    {% for obj in objects %}
    <li>{{obj}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  {% if show_button_x %}
  <button>X</button>
  {% endif %}

  <button unicorn:click="toggle_button_x">Toggle Button X</button>

</div>
```

After clicking on the `Toggle Button X` the `<button>X</button>` appears correctly but my list of `objects` disappears. As if it would re-initialized the `MyObject.objects.none()` from the start of the view. Ist this possible?

Am I doing something wrong or does anyone know a good workaround?

*Unfortunately there is no `django-unicorn` tag on stackoverflow, yet. Also there are not that many ressources about this incredible easy and powerful framework.*